# How to download and implement dependencies in Gradle during pre-build stage?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I need to create an aar for sdk, with all the dependencies already implemented.
I read that I can use a task in Gradle to download the dependencies and implement them.

I added the following code at the bottom of my gradle file, after the dependencies part:

```
task myTask{

    compile('com.tawkon.data.lib:connected-car-dt-lib:2.0.23@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile('com.tawkon.data.lib:netchanger-lib:1.25@aar'){ transitive = true }
    compile('com.tawkon.sce:datalib-sce:1.6@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile('com.tawkon.data.lib:indoor-outdoor-lib:1.6.9@aar') { transitive = true }
}

preBuild.dependsOn myTask
```

When I tried to sync I got the following message:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.tawkon.data.lib:connected-car-dt-lib:2.0.23@aar, build_8hqn5ss9fc94c31vqz22187z7$_run_closure3$_closure25@1b1bbb2f] on task ':datalib:myTask' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

What does this error mean, and how to fix it?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying and why you are adding dependencies dynamically. Keep attention because the aar file doesn't contain the transitive dependencies.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I want to create an aar with all the dependencies implemented, for the case if someone else will use it, it wouldn't try to get the dependencies from the repository. The reason for this is, that if the repository server is down, I want to have a backup aar file with all dependencies implemented in advance.

Comment: The aar file doesn't contain the dependencies. You should upload your aar in a maven repo, and the pom file will contain all the dependencies needed. In this way adding the library, gradle will be able to download all transitive dependencies.

Comment: I see, however I dont want it to download anything, I want it to be with all the dependencies in advance. The reason for this is, if for some reason maven repo is down (and it happened already) I want to have aar with all the dependencies implemented, that the user can use instead, as a back up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Implementation instead of compile as:

```
implementation('com.tawkon.data.lib:connected-car-dt-lib:2.0.23@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, how ever I still get the same message: 
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments....

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file here?

Comment: @rya The issue is not related to the use of `implementation()` instead of `compile()`.